# CSS - Targeting a specific element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="B">
   blah
   blah
   blah
</div>

<section class="A">
    <div class="B"/> <!-- THIS -->
    <div/>
</section>
```

How can I target the div with the B class inside the section, and only it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select it like this

```
.A>.B{

}
```

This is known as **CSS element>element Selector**

The syntax is as follows

```
element > element {
    css declarations;
}
```

you can see an example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_element_gt)..

Answer (score 0):

You should write :

```
section.A div.B {
}
```

If you want target just one element consider use **id** instead **class**.

Comment: I added clarification in my post, this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Tsury check out now.

Comment: Someone answered '.A>.B{' as a more general way of doing it. This is what I was looking for. Thanks anyway!